# Custom array indexing

Tags: python, python-2.x, meta-programming

Note that this code is not going to be used for anything, it's more of a thought experiment. I've been seeing a lot of NumPy code lately and noticed that they use a custom indexing process, presumably by defining an object's `__getitem__` method. I wrote the following class that allows for a multi-dimensional array to be indexed as `ls[1,2]` instead of `ls[1][2]`.

Is there a better way to write this method? It seems unnecessary to be keeping track of `current` as the item look-up is descended, but I can't think of a way to avoid it.

```
class Array(list):
    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        current = super(self.__class__, self)
        for index in indices:
            current = current.__getitem__(index)
        return current

a = Array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
           [[0,1,2],[9,8,7]]])
print a[1,0,2] # 2
```

Comment: Actually, I find your implementation very wise and uncomplicated. It maybe just misses some comments to make it obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying that there's nothing wrong with your approach, and almost nothing wrong with your implementation. Just two things I would like to remark.

## Use of `super`.

Because of your use of `super`, you actively prevent subclassing. In Python 2.7, you're supposed to spell the name out long:

```
current = super(Array, self)
```

Consider this:

```
class Brray(Array): pass
b = Brray([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
           [[0,1,2],[9,8,7]]])
print b[1, 0, 2]
```

This gives us

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

By using `super(Array, self)` instead, everything is fine again.

## Subclassing list

You're subclassing list, which causes `a = Array(...)` to make a shallow copy of the supplied iterable. I myself would prefer composition:

```
class Array(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped
    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        current = self._wrapped
        for index in indices:
            current = current[index]
        return current
```

(This is also aided by the fact that I don't like calling 'dunder' (double under) methods directly.

Answer (score 2):

While your code is really great and i made an alternative using python mapping. The reason is that map() is like "for" in C code as explained in the article below.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops

```
class Array(list):
    def __mapItem(self, index):
        # we are creating a function in order to use map()
        # which does exactly the same thing as yours
        self.current = self.current.__getitem__(index)

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        self.current = super(self.__class__, self)
        # map every index to the target item using the __mapItem function
        map(self.__mapItem, indices)
        return self.current

a = Array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
           [[0,1,2],[9,8,7]]])
print a[1,0,2] # 2
```

Comment: That's interesting, I'm going to try timing them both and see what happens.

Comment: It seems like the original class performs look-ups twice as quickly. I'd assume that this is because of the instance variable used in your solution. The `dis` code isn't terribly enlightening because I'm not terribly familiar with it, but it seems like a major difference is the use of `LOAD_FAST` and `STORE_FAST` versus `LOAD_ATTR` and `STORE_ATTR`.

Comment: I just timed both in Python 3.4, and your class is quicker by about 10% there, so it seems like the changes to `map` between versions might be the big difference.

Comment: I see , thanks for taking the time to check this out , i don't actually use python 3 and i can't really explain why it is slower in python 2 although it seems like it performs less steps based on `dis` ( 4 ).

Comment: It's an interesting thought experiment, but I'd really like to say 'No!!!!!' to this approach, mainly based on the fact that `__getitem__` influences class state, and the fact that `map` is used with a method that has side-effects (changing `current`). I greatly prefer the original approach over this.